# Difference between classical magnet and quantum spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

A classical spin (a tiny magnet) starting at rest will feel a torque and try to align with a magnetic field (if it starts almost antiparallel it will periodically align and misalign).  A spin ½ particle, instead, will precess and the spin vertical component will never change or attempt to align (I am assuming B in the vertical z direction). How does this behavior change as the spin goes from ½ to very large when we should be able to recover the classical behavior? What makes it align instead of precess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a good question. To be concrete, imagine that we have a magnetic dipole $\mathbf m = m \hat x$ in a uniform magnetic field $\mathbf B = B \hat y$. This system will experience a torque $\boldsymbol \tau = \mathbf m \times \mathbf B = mB \hat z$, which implies that its angular momentum will begin to change in the $+\hat z$ direction.

If the system consists of a single spin-1/2 particle at rest, then its angular momentum is just its spin. In accordance with the previous (semiclassical) argument, its spin will begin to precess around the $y$-axis.

On the other hand, imagine that the system consists of a chain of spin-1/2 particles which lies along the $x$-axis, and whose spins all point in the $+\hat x$ direction.  In principle, the spins could all precess in the same manner as before. However, the interactions between the members of the chain are such that the system *prefers* to be magnetized in the direction of the chain. More specifically, the cumulative interaction energy between members of the chain is minimized if they are aligned along the direction of the chain (the system's so-called *easy axis*).

There is another way for the angular momentum of the chain to change in the $+\hat z$ direction, however, and that is for the chain to start rotating about the $\hat z$-axis.  There is no energy barrier to overcome here - even the smallest torque will cause the chain to undergo this rotation (in the absence of any opposing torques such as friction) and so this is the behavior we would expect to see, barring fringe cases like enormous magnetic fields.

Tl;dr:  Interactions between dipoles (or rather, *magnetic domains* in the case of a macroscopic permanent magnet) resist the precession of individual dipoles (or domains) in favor of the bulk rotation of the magnet itself. Free, individual point dipoles can't rotate in this way and there are no competing interactions, so they precess instead.

Comment: I fail to see why the spin will begin to precess around the y-axis, classically, the torque will make it rotate about the z axis to try to get it aligned with the magnetic field. What you said is true for a quantum 1/2 spin, I can see it in the solution, but i have no intuition as why it behaves differently than the classical one.

Comment: I can understand the second part, so assuming that the quantum case does not behave classically at all, a bunch of interacting spins will? then a single quantum spin s=10^20 (as oppossed to a bunch of 1/2 spins) will not align with B like the classical one, as I assumed? it will still precess?

Comment: Also, thanks a lot for the answer, I just need the clarification to make sure I understood what you stated

Comment: @PatoGalmarini It is perhaps counterintuitive, but what you say is not true; the torque does **not** try to align the dipole with the magnetic field. This is somewhat analogous to the famous (and similarly counterintuitive) [bicycle wheel demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jE58kN8f_iU) from introductory physics, in which the gravitational field takes the place of the magnetic field. Notice that the torque does not cause the angular momentum of the wheel to align with the gravitational field, but rather to precess around it - precisely the same thing is true for the dipole.

Comment: Damn, that is embarrasing. Thanks again.

Comment: @PatoGalmarini Nothing to be embarrassed about - every time I do that demonstration, I rediscover that angular momentum is witchcraft as far as my intuition is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to show directly how the quantum system approaches the classical limit without introducing semiclassical descriptions like *precession* or more than one spin.

The key concept is that the classical limit can be recovered in the limit of large quantum numbers. Saying that a quantum particle has spin S means that the eigenvalue of the $ |\hat{S} |$ operator is $\hbar \sqrt{S(S+1)}$, while the possible eigenvalues $S_z$ of the $\hat S_z$ operator are the $2 S +1$ values $\hbar S$, $\hbar (S-1)$, $\hbar (S-2)$, $\dots$,$\hbar (-S+1)$,$- \hbar S$.

Taking into account the interaction with an external magnetic field in the direction of the positive $z$ axis, $\vec B = B \vec{\hat z}$,
$$
\Delta \hat H=-g B \vec S_z, 
$$
where $g$ is the [gyromagnetic ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyromagnetic_ratio), the minimum energy corresponds to the maximum eigenvalue of $\hat S_z$.

Therefore, the minimum energy is the same as the energy of a classical magnetic dipole of magnetic moment proportional to $\hbar S_z= \hbar S$, although the modulus of the quantum spin operator is not $\hbar S$, but $\hbar \sqrt{S(S+1)}$. However, the relative difference between $\sqrt{S(S+1)}$ and $S$ vanishes as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{S}}$ in the limit of large $S$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the motion of a magnetic dipole in the magnetic field is either precess around or simply align with $\vec{B}$, is not the matter of choosing Quantum Mechanics or Classical Mechanics, but only determined by the property of the magnetic dipole.

In Classical Mechanics, it's possible for a magnetic dipole to precess around the $\vec{B}$, as long as its magnetic moment is parallel to a non-zero angular momentum on its own axis. The principle is actually the same as a spinning top precessing around the direction of $\vec{g}$.

For a spin 1/2 particle in Quantum Mechanics, its magnetic moment is always accompanied by a spin momentum, so even in a classical description it will precess around $\vec{B}$.